# What virtual desktop software can catch programs into their desktop?

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, classification

Say I need Firefox to always be launched in desktop 2, and in whatever desktop if I open it I will be switched to desktop 2. This is similar to Tab Groups addon of Firefox, where tabs can be automatically classified by their names. The native virtual desktop feature of Windows 10 or VirtuaWin don't seem to have this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## VirtuaWin

Apparently I didn't explore the program sufficiently. This tool is so great.

1. Open Windows Rules

[image]

2. Config as you wish. It even has a helpful help file.

[image]